# Oracle memory_target recomended

Tags: oracle

Please, help me.

- I have a Dell Server with 8 GB RAM,
  with Windows Server 2003 32-bit  (4GB recogniced only)
- I have a Oracle DB 11g R1 standard one

Recently I got performance issues in my DB.

These are its parameters:

```
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -------------
archive_lag_target                   integer     0 
db_flashback_retention_target        integer     1440 
fast_start_io_target                 integer     0 
fast_start_mttr_target               integer     0 
memory_max_target                    big integer 820M 
memory_target                        big integer 820M 
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 0 
sga_target                           big integer 0 
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please could you advise me what parameters I should modify to increase the performance. (Considering the server's capacity)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of performance issues? Slow queries? Perhaps they just should be tuned (and no, "just" doesn't mean that this is a simple task).

Comment: Thaks Littlefoot:  I get these messages "ORA-04030: memoria de proceso insuficiente al intentar asignar 123404 bytes (QERHJ hash-joi,kllcqas:kllsltba)".   Also i noticed that in a few days the database "diag" grew a lot  (trace files so huge).....

Comment: Huh. You seem to be limited by 32-bit operating system. If you could address 4GB you have but can't use, things might be better. On  4GB only, with Windows (and additional software you might have and use) taking its piece of cake, there's no that much RAM for Oracle. I'm afraid there's nothing much I can suggest. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, and what if modify some parameter like pga_aggregate_target,

Comment: I'd set it to a value larger than 0, that's for sure, but - can you afford it? On the other hand, there's nothing to lose, you can always put it back.

Comment: what values do you recomend for it?

Comment: See this; calculate yourself. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams157.htm#REFRN10165